# How to fix duplicate content caused by editing titles that creates new URLs for the same page?

Tags: seo, canonical-url, rel-canonical, url-slug

We have custom CMS for our site, after three years we find problem in index page.
This is structure of URL :
`example.com/ads/buy/545564/title`
Now we find when user change title of ads, google re-indexes this page. user may also change the title several times and now Google results for this ads like this:

1. result 1 : 
   title 1
   `example.com/ads/buy/545564/title1`
2. result 2 : 
   title 2
   `example.com/ads/buy/545564/title2`
3. result 3 : 
   title 3
   `example.com/ads/buy/545564/title3`
4. result 4 : 
   title 4
   `example.com/ads/buy/545564/title4`

Also canonical tag structure have title and caused different pages to be indexed.
Now we found a solution to this problem But for the ads that will be published from today.
We guess the number of these links is between 10,000 and 15,000.
**What should we do for ads that have already been indexed?**

Comment: why are there individual URLs for ads? Shouldn't ads be part of a page rather than a page into themselves? If you do have a page reach ad, why would it be indexed in search engines? Ads are not usually appropriate content to try to get search engines to index

Comment: @StephenOstermiller The subject of the website is advertising (like craigslist,org or olx.com). for this reason we use "ads" word in URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure your canonical are set correctly. There should be only one canonical for each page. So, any two URLs that you consider the same *must* have the same canonical. From you example, it looks like the `title` portion should not be part of the canonical.

Essentially that is all you have to do. The rest is waiting. Search Engine bots crawl the web to discover content which gets added to be index but the whole process is asynchronous and similarly to remove content when a link is discovered as no longer valid.

The best thing you can do to help along is to serve `301 Permanent Redirect` from links that change. This will speed up, at least Google, to replace these links with their new destination. It could be a pain though because to do that you must remember past URLs. If you do nothing though and your canonicals are set correctly, it will be  sorted out in a few weeks or so as the search index gets updated.

Comment: I'd recommend including the current title in the canonical URL. If the URL changes for users search engines will pick up on the new canonical and only index one of the two URLs then. Putting in a canonical that doesn't match what the user sees isn't something that I would recommend.

Comment: So there are two ways. the first is use 301 Redirect but must remember past URLs. and the second is remove title from canonical. But one question. a word that is searched on Google has a positive effect if it is in the URL. it's true? if the title is removed, will it have any effect on SEO?

Comment: Exactly. It is one of 100s of factors for SEO, so optimally, yes the title in the URL makes it incrementally better ranked but if there are plenty of other indicators that match the title in <H1> or other headings, plus occurs in the content, the effect is lessened. Conversely putting a title that does not appear in the content will not contribute to ranking because it's about many factors that confirm what a page is about.